# powerlevel10k slanted theme not aligned in VSCode integrated terminal

Tags: shell, zsh, visual-studio-code, oh-my-zsh

I have powerlevel10k installed on my zsh.

On VSCode integrated terminal, the `slanted` theme is not aligned properly, even with `MesloLGS NF` font installed and `terminal.integrated.fontfamily` set to `MesloLGS NF`.

[p10k theme not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwrUB.png)

[how it looks on iTerm2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEIi0.png)

It is displayed correctly on other terminals like iTerm2. Other themes like `angled` or `round` are displayed properly too. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo in MelsoLGS NF. Use MesloLGS NF instead.

[image: Terminal using MesloLGS NF in Visual Studio Code]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My setting is set to `MesloLGS NF` but I made a typo while writing the question. I updated the question. I'm sorry.